# Is there a word for words that form another word when read in reverse?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for words that form another word when read in reverse?
Examples: stop -> pots

Comment: If someone asks you to spell "part A" backwards, don't do it.
It's a Trap.

Comment: No, there isn't any special name for words like that. Especially given English spelling, it wouldn't be of any use.